# onClick issue with navigation dropdown for container(needs double clicks to dropdown)

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, onclick

I have trouble with my onClick function within my JS file
When a tab is opened, and I try to click on the second link, the new tab won't open unless the link is clicked twice.
here is the html code:

`<body>
    <nav>
        <div id="navContainer">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='1'>1</a></li>
                <li> <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='2'>2</a></li>
                <li> <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='3'>3</a></li>
                <li> <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='4'>4</a></li>
                <li> <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='5'>5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id = "tabCont" class="tabContainer">
            <div id="1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="2" >
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
        <div id="3" >
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
        <div id="4" >
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
        <div id="5" >
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>`

and here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
document.menuIsOpen = false;

$('.tabContainer > div').hide();
$('.tabContainer > div:first-of-type').hide();

$('.tabButton').click(function(event) {
    if (document.menuIsOpen == false) {
        document.menuIsOpen = true;
        event.preventDefault();

        $('.tabContainer > div').hide();
        $("#" + $(this).attr('data-openTab')).toggle("slow").css("display", "block");

        $('.tabButton').click(function(event) {

            $('.tabContainer > div').hide();
            $("#" + $(this).attr('data-openTab')).show().css("display", "block");
        });
    } else {
        document.menuIsOpen = false;
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.tabContainer > div').hide("slow");
        $('.tabContainer > div:first-of-type').hide("slow");

    }

    $('.closeButton').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('.tabContainer > div').hide("slow");
        $('.tabContainer > div:first-of-type').hide("slow");
    });
});

$('.tabContainer > div').hide();
$('.tabContainer > div:first-of-type').hide();
});
```

I'm sure I have really messy code but it works as it should APART from the onClick issue.
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Is the is complete code? It seems strangely formated! Why are you creating another onclick inside the onclick? That may be the problem.

Comment: I added that so that when another link is clicked it would drop down the other content right away instead of closing the first content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div id="navContainer">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='1'>1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='2'>2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='3'>3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='4'>4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href='' class='tabButton' data-openTab='5'>5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id = "tabCont" class="tabContainer">
        <div id="1">1
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
        <div id="2">2
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
        <div id="3">3
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
        <div id="4">4
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
        <div id="5">5
            <a href="" class="closeButton"> CLOSE </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
    document.menuIsOpen = false;
    $('.tabContainer > div').hide();
    $('.tabButton').click(function(event) {
        var
            open = $("#" + $(this).attr('data-openTab')),
            isOpened = open.is('.opened');

        event.preventDefault();
        if (document.menuIsOpen) {
            document.menuIsOpen = false;
            $('.opened').hide("slow").removeClass('opened');
        }
        if (!isOpened) {
            document.menuIsOpen = true;
            open.addClass('opened').show("slow").css("display", "block");
        }
    });
    $('.closeButton').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.opened').hide("slow").removeClass('opened');
    });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/mcgv4gok/